# Failed to pass value to component in angular

Tags: angular

I wanted to pass a value from one Service to another Service.

I set the value in the FirstService as observable, and SecondService subscribes the value. Once the value gets changed, the Service will react.

"first.service.ts"

```
export class FirstService extends Service {

    private readonly firstValue =
      new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

    getFirstValue(): Observable<string> {
        return this.firstValue;
    }

    setFirstValue(value: string) {
        this.firstValue.next(value);
    }
}
```

"second.service.ts"

```
export class SecondService extends Service {
    private secondValue: string;

    constructor(http: HttpClient, private firstService: FirstService ) {
        super(http);
        firstService.getFirstValue().subscribe(
            (val) => {
                this.secondValue = val;
          }
        );  
    }
}
```

But every time I entered the url of SecondService's Component, the Service(SecondService) is reconstructed and the Service it subscribes(FirstService) is also initialized. So I lost the value I set before.

What should I do to pass the value to the Service. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FirstService extends Service {
    firstValue = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
    $firstValue = this.firstValue.asObservable();

    setFirstValue(value: string) {
        this.firstValue.next(value);
    }
}
```

And remove any references of 1st service in modules and components.
In the 2nd service:

```
firstService.firstValue$.subscribe(val => this.secondValue = val);
```

If you want your 1st service not to be initialized every time, you should put the `root` parameter in the injector.

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
}
```

For more information: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

For even more information : https://indepth.dev/angulars-root-and-any-provider-scopes/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have done as above, except that removing any references of 1st service in modules and components. Because some operations in 1st components need to call 1st service. 

And the result is 1st service is still initialized again. Are there any else methods that deserves trying? Thanks again!

Comment: `except that removing any references of 1st service in modules` That is what I suggest you to do. If you do like this, the 1st Component can inject Service just by refer it in constructor. Otherwise it won't work